# Monero blockchain explorer compilation not working ubuntu 16.04

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, blockchain, linux, ubuntu

Hi I am working on monero blockchain explorer, Trying to work with this [git repo](https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer). I have tried too many times but unfortunately couldn't get success yet. Right now I am facing this error.

> CMake Error: The source directory "/mnt/volume-nyc3-01/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
>   Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

while running `cmake -DMONERO_DIR=/path/to/monero_folder` command please help me I have to complete it soon. I have no time.

As per @jtgrassie I have added `''` at the end of the command and it ran. but I got these response on result too. I don't know it will be an issue or not

> -- FindMonero Xmr_COMMON_LIBRARIES Xmr_COMMON_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_BLOCKS_LIBRARIES Xmr_BLOCKS_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_CRYPTONOTE_BASIC_LIBRARIES Xmr_CRYPTONOTE_BASIC_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_CRYPTONOTE_CORE_LIBRARIES Xmr_CRYPTONOTE_CORE_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_MULTISIG_LIBRARIES Xmr_MULTISIG_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_CRYPTONOTE_PROTOCOL_LIBRARIES Xmr_CRYPTONOTE_PROTOCOL_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_DAEMONIZER_LIBRARIES Xmr_DAEMONIZER_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_MNEMONICS_LIBRARIES Xmr_MNEMONICS_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_EPEE_LIBRARIES Xmr_EPEE_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_LMDB_LIBRARIES Xmr_LMDB_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_DEVICE_LIBRARIES Xmr_DEVICE_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_BLOCKCHAIN_DB_LIBRARIES Xmr_BLOCKCHAIN_DB_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_RINGCT_LIBRARIES Xmr_RINGCT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_WALLET_LIBRARIES Xmr_WALLET_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_CNCRYPTO_LIBRARIES Xmr_CNCRYPTO_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_EASYLOGGING_LIBRARIES Xmr_EASYLOGGING_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_VERSION_LIBRARIES Xmr_VERSION_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
>   -- FindMonero Xmr_CHECKPOINTS_LIBRARIES Xmr_CHECKPOINTS_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND

And now I am running `make` command it is giving me this error

> In file included from /mnt/volume-nyc3-01/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer/src/MicroCore.h:10:0,
>                    from /mnt/volume-nyc3-01/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer/src/MicroCore.cpp:5:
>   /mnt/volume-nyc3-01/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer/src/monero_headers.h:19:21: fatal error: version.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>   src/CMakeFiles/myxrm.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/myxrm.dir/MicroCore.cpp.o' failed
>   make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/myxrm.dir/MicroCore.cpp.o] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:254: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/myxrm.dir/all' failed
>   make[1](https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer): *** [src/CMakeFiles/myxrm.dir/all] Error 2
>   Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

Following Commands:

## Install monero dependencies

1: sudo apt update

2: sudo apt install git build-essential cmake libboost-all-dev miniupnpc libunbound-dev graphviz doxygen libunwind8-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libgtest-dev libreadline-dev libzmq3-dev libsodium-dev libpcsclite-dev

## cloning monero project

3: git clone --recursive https://github.com/monero-project/monero

4: cd monero/

5: git checkout -b last_release v0.12.1.0

6: sudo make

## download the source code

7: git clone https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer.git

## enter the downloaded sourced code folder

8: cd onion-monero-blockchain-explorer

## make a build folder and enter it

9: sudo mkdir build && cd build

10: sudo cmake -DMONERO_DIR=/path/to/monero_folder

11: sudo make

Answer (score 1):

From the readme:

```
# altearnatively can use: cmake -DMONERO_DIR=/path/to/monero_folder ..
```

Note the `..` at the end.

This is also assuming you have followed all the preceding instructions (including changing directories):

```
git clone https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer.git

# enter the downloaded sourced code folder
cd onion-monero-blockchain-explorer

# make a build folder and enter it
mkdir build && cd build
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer please see my updated question. Really appreciated your help. :)

Comment: and yes I have followed the preceding instructions.

Comment: Have you built monero and set the correct path after -DMONERO_DIR= ?

Comment: Yes I have built monero and setted the correct path while running cmake

Comment: What path are you using for the MONERO_DIR? Note you can only run the make command if you followed all the instructions (e.g. cloning building monero into specified path). Otherwise you have to use cmake with the flag to point to your monero path.

Comment: `/mnt/volume-nyc3-01/monero` this is my path to monero.

Comment: So you have to use: cmake -DDMONERO_DIR=/mnt/volume-nyc3-01/monero .. Assuming you did a git clone of monero in /mnt/volume-nyc3-01. I'm certain you have a path problem as the build isn't finding monero sources. You could try following the instructions to the letter with monero in your home directory. If that fails I suggest a github issue should be filed.

Comment: I have follerd all the instructions, I have compiled monero in `/mnt/volume-nyc3-01/monero` directory and I ran cmake command like this `sudo cmake -DMONERO_DIR=/mnt/volume-nyc3-01/monero ..` now I am running make command and getting the mentioned issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78902/discussion-between-owais-aslam-and-jtgrassie).